# adding to the beginning of lists in C#

Tags: c#, list

I'm retuning a list of months from a function.

I'm looking to see if there's an elegant solution to adding 3 elements to the beginning of that list.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: When you say list, do you mean System.Collections.ArrayList, System.Array, Month[], System.Collections.Generic.List<Moth>, System.IEnumerable<Month> or something else?  Depending on what type you return the solutions could vary significantly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`List.Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) for that, it takes the index at which you want to add the new item, i.e. to add at the beginning:

```
list.Insert(0, item);
```

Also to add *multiple* items at the same time you can use [`List.InsertRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which takes an `IEnumerable` as second parameter:

```
list.InsertRange(0, itemCollection);
```

Comment: Don't forget list.InsertRange

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [InsertRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> listOfMonths = new List<int>();
// ... insert months here
listOfMonths.InsertRange(0, new int[] { 1, 2 ,3 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go crazy...

```
    // in a static class in a namespace you can see
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> second, IEnumerable<T> first)
    {
        foreach (var x in first)
        {
            yield return x;
        }
        foreach (var x in second)
        {
            yield return x;
        }
    }

    ...

    var newListOfMonths = listOfMonths.Prepend(someExtraItems).ToList();
```